# Remove a certain character from a string, without removing said character from the beginning and end of a string, if present

Tags: java, string, character

As the title says, I want to remove a specific character (in this instance it is 'e')  from a string, but I don't want to remove it if that letter is at the beginning or end of the string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RemoveE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String s;
    String st;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    s = in.nextLine();


    st = s.replaceAll("e", "");

    System.out.println(st);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to use 2 boolean variables, which tell you if there is that char at the beginning or end, then remove them all and if booleans are true just add them back.

```
boolean front = s.startsWith("e");
boolean end = s.endsWith("e");
s = s.replaceAll("e", "");

if(front)
   s="e"+s;
if(end)
   s=s+"e";
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: Almost, but not quite - what if front and end are both true? If-statements should add to st, not s.

Comment: Yep you are right. Thanks for the warning, it is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
st = s.length() < 3 ? s : s.charAt(0) + s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).replaceAll("e","") + s.charAt(s.length()-1);
```